# How can I tell where an email account is hosted?

Tags: email

I have a client that has an old email account that is being used to send porn spam but they don't know where it is hosted or how to close it down. I recently helped move the domain registration with hopes of gaining more control over it, but that has not been helpful.

I checked senderbase.org and it points to RackSpace but when I contacted RackSpace support they had no record of an account for the domain in question.

Is there any way to determine where an email account is hosted? If so how?

Comment: Check the headers in one of the messages.

Comment: It says the originating IP is 177.23.143.146.

Comment: It says the originating IP is 177.23.143.146 (Brazil) and another one has it coming from 190.171.242.178 (Bolivia).

Comment: Sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing.

Comment: You can find out the MX records for a given domain via `dig domain.tld mx` which will indicate what servers (if any) have been configured to receive e-mail for the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoofing sender addresses is a common spoofing technique.  As you have control of the domain adding a SPF record with a '-all' final policy should discourage spoofing addresses in the domain. If there are email addresses in the domain then a policy of "v=spf1 mx -all" would be appropriate, otherwise use a policy like "v=spf1 -all".

Given that neither of the IP addresses you listed have PTR records, it is likely that the Spam is being sent by a botnet.

If your client is getting bounces to his address, then it is likely backscatter.  If it is being sent from the client to the client, then the mail server's policies should be adjusted.  It is best to require authentication before allowing users on the Internet to send from the mail server's domain(s).

I've recently seen a surge in spam originating from long discontinued addresses.  These are sent to the expired address to the new address.  While I have the log data, the mail server's policy ensures the email is rejected.

If the client is not using the address, then it should be possible to disable it in the mail server.  For some mail servers this can be done with a flag in the `/etc/aliases`.  This should cause servers receiving mail from the address to reject it.  This may result in backscatter spam to your client's address., but if the account is disabled it should be dropped in transit.

It is too late now, but implementing BATV (Bounce Address Tag Validation) can be used to identify bounces from spoofed email.  This should to be implemented on the mail server for a week or two before you can safely bounce email.  This needs to be implemented by the mail server administrator hosting your client's email.

Comment: BillThor, this is very helpful. My big challenge on this other than the spam is determining where the account is hosted. Is there any way to control this email account at the domain registration level or do I need to be able to access the account wherever it is to do this?

Comment: The eMail account will be hosted wherever the MX for the domain points.  In the case of a botnet, which appears to be the case, where the account is hosted is irrelevant.  The account does not even need to exist.  As it appears the client is getting mail for the address, it will be hosted where he get the mail for the email address  I've added an additional tactics to the answer.